# In which case OnStop() of .NET Window Service will not fire?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I want to know In which case OnStop() of .NET Window Service will not fire?

will it fire when computer sudden restart,power failure , Shutdown or any other conditions?

Comment: It won't work when you don't implement it correctly.  You can safely assume the service stops on a power failure or shutdown.  Strange question.

Comment: @ Hans i didnt mention that onstop() function in not woring it working fine ... i just want assure for above question because it is running on server..  @Steven i cant check as it is on server and i know it will not work when computer unplugged ... i want to know this onStop() function will call before above conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will fire in exactly the situation that the machine's Service Control Manager receives a Stop instruction for that service.

This will happen if someone chooses to perform the Stop action through the Services MMC snap-in (either directly to your service or to a service that is marked as a dependency), or if someone issues an `sc stop` command at the command line (again, either to your service or a dependency).

Or, it could happen if any arbitrary program running on the machine (with sufficient permissions) connects to the Service Control Manager and issues the stop command.

> will it fire when computer sudden restart,power failure , Shutdown or any other conditions?

- Sudden restart - no
- Power failure - as addressed in the comments, obviously not.
- Shutdown - no
- Any other - as addressed above

There is an option to receive shutdown events - see [`CanShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canshutdown.aspx) and [`OnShutdown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onshutdown.aspx). You can also handle some power state change events (see [`OnPowerEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onpowerevent.aspx)).